# how do you pull an image out of an array and push it into a div?

Tags: javascript, stack

I'm trying to teach myself javascript.

I have an array of images, and I'm trying to get them to get poped out of the array and simultaneously pushed into a div so that they're displayed on the screen and no longer inside of the array.

I'm doing this so that I can attempt to create a black jack card game.  naturally, I'd need to know how to do this.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Edit: I've tried the following:

```
var cards = [], i=0;
while(i<54){
var card = {'1.png': 1};
card.number = ++i;
card.value = "1.png";
cards.push(dealerField) }
```

"dealerFIeld" is my div.  I know that there are errors, and it doesn't work.  But I think the basic idea of what I'd lie to do is there.

Comment: Its very simple using jquery: Use $().remove to pop remove it from array and $().html() to put in div

Comment: `pop()` will remove an object from the array and return said object.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [jQuery library](http://jquery.com/) to expand your js functionality. Then use something like:

```
$("#a_div_marked_by_an_id").html('string you want to replace the div contents with');
```

you can also of course instead of a `'string'` just use a variable like `varName`

The above example would insert into

```
<div id="a_div_marked_by_an_id></div>
```

creating

```
<div id="a_div_marked_by_an_id>string you want to replace the div contents with</div>
```

Comment: yes, excellent: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/45176/when-is-use-jquery-not-a-valid-answer-to-a-javascript-question

Comment: Yeah I wondered about that issue -- I assumed if he knew about jQ and wanted to avoid it, he would've made it explicitly stated because he'd know the most easy/common response would involve it. Instead, since he didn't, I assumed he's so new to js that he doesn't know about jQ, and/or how "real world" (completely debatable how accurate that adjective is) js tasks these days seem to never have a "no jquery!" requirement, so that he would be open to expanding his options. I could be wrong, but I feel like because it's so intuitive to respond to js questions with jq options, ppl should say explct

Comment: I think the key difference here is what jQuery brings to the table for this solution.  jQuery is fundamentally a library that takes the pain out of manipulating DOM, styles, and AJAX. That's what it's good at.  OP has a problem where only a very minor part of it involved the DOM, and adding jQuery is unnecessary for that task.  Beyond that, OP indicated that they were trying to "teach [themselves] javascript," so it's really a disservice to shuffle them away from the core language and have them learn a library instead.  That's my take on it.

Comment: "teach [themselves] javascript," that is a fair point. I just remember not even a year ago I was in a very similar position and catered my answer to what I would've appreciated to hear/learn, but if the SO policy is as you linked, then that's that.

Comment: I wouldn't conflate my opinion / interpretation with SO policy :D  Also, I didn't downvote your answer because it is another option, so don't feel like I'm saying you're __wrong__.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, don't redefine your variable inside the loop, that's just wasteful.
Then, you'll need to create an image tag and append it to your "dealerField" inside the loop.

```
var cards = [],
    i=0,
    card = {},
    img;

while( i < 54 ){
    card.number = ++i;
    card.value = i + ".png";
    img = document.createElement( "img" );
    img.src = card.value;
    img.alt = card.number;

    document.getElementByID( "dealerField" ).appendChild( img );
}
```

Now, some of this is a little unnecessary, like writing to that object and then immediately copying it into the image.  So you could do something like this instead:

```
var i=0,
    img;

while( i < 54 ){
    img = document.createElement( "img" );
    img.alt = ++i;
    img.src = i + ".png";

    document.getElementByID( "dealerField" ).appendChild( img );
}
```

## More

After re-reading your question, it seems like your array `cards` might actually have something in it - like the card objects.  I can't be sure, obviously, because you didn't put any example data in there, but here's what the same thing looks like but using the array of cards as the data source:

```
// cards is an array of card objects with some arbitrary structure
var i = 0,
    len = cards.length,
    card,img;

for( i; i < len; i++){
    img = document.createElement( "img" );
    card = cards[ i ];

    img.src = card.value;
    img.alt = card.number;

    document.getElementByID( "dealerField" ).appendChild( img );
}
```